# How to fix XSS vulnerabilites in javascript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

We're using fortify to scan asp.net source code & it is complaining below error:

The method lambda() in dashboard_handler.js sends unvalidated data to a web browser on line 61, which can result in the browser executing malicious code.Sending unvalidated data to a web browser can result in the browser executing malicious code

We've below code on line 61:
Tool says that code on line 61 sends un validated data to a web browser.

```
$el = $("<div class='dashboard-column'><i class='fa fa-caret-right'></i> <div class='column-title " + items[bucket][itemsNo - 1][1] + "'><span>" + bucket + "</span><i class='fa fa-caret-right caret-right'></i><i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i></div> </div>");
```

Can any one tell me how to fix this XSS vulnerability?

Comment: Well, no, because you've given no context.

Comment: No. no one will not tell you how to fix,without proper input

Comment: This is summary provided in the tool: The method lambda() in dashboard_handler.js sends unvalidated data to a web browser on line 61, which can result in the browser executing malicious code.Sending unvalidated data to a web browser can result in the browser executing malicious code.

Comment: Additionally the code used is : $cat = $("<div class='column-item " +
                        nameCateg[1] +
                        "'> <div class='item-name'>  <div class='icon'><i class='fa fa-check'></i><i class='fa fa-hourglass-2'></i><i class='fa fa-times'></i><i class='fa fa-hand-stop-o'></i></div>" +
                        nameCateg[0] +
                        "</div> </div>");
                    $el.append($cat);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is coming from the user and it's not properly sanitized, both `"<div class='column-title " + items[bucket][itemsNo - 1][1] + "'>"` and `"<span>" + bucket + "</span>"` are potential XSS attack vectors because the attacker can just insert any HTML they want, including script tags.

You can rewrite the code so that it doesn't build the HTML by concatenating strings (which is a bad idea in general, not only from security standpoint.)

```
$el = $("<div class='dashboard-column'><i class='fa fa-caret-right'></i></div>");
$div = $("<div class='column-title'>").addClass( items[bucket][itemsNo - 1][1] ).appendTo( $el );
$span = $("<span>").text(bucket).appendTo($div);
$div.append("<i class='fa fa-caret-right caret-right'></i><i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i>");
```

Comment: Thanks @JJJ.. this worked. But same I tried to applied for the below code but was no luck.. COuld you please assist me in the following for the same issue?

$cat = $("<div class='column-item " +
                        nameCateg[1] +
                        "'> <div class='item-name'>  <div class='icon'><i class='fa fa-check'></i><i class='fa fa-hourglass-2'></i><i class='fa fa-times'></i><i class='fa fa-hand-stop-o'></i></div>" +
                        nameCateg[0] +
                        "</div> </div>");